# Docker shared volume is not readable for a container after changing volume contents

Tags: docker, nginx, shared, volumes

I have got following compose file where i'm sharing some generated html data from Jenkins container to the host drive and reading this data by Nginx container from the host drive. I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 on AWS.

The problem is that I can read contents of the `jenkins/workspace/allure-report` only once. After updating of the html data it becomes inaccessible for Nginx and it throws 403 status code.

I tried all the possible solutions but nothing works. The only **ugly** solution is to restart Nginx container after every html data updating. I don't like this way and looking for some inbuilt docker features to resolve this.

What didn't help: sharing volume straight between containers without using docker host drive, using `rslave` option, using docker separate volume that can be used as buffer between the two containers... I believe it should be much more easier!

```
version: '2'

services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: "jenkins/jenkins"
    ports:
      - "8088:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home

  selenoid:
    container_name: selenoid
    network_mode: bridge
    image: "aerokube/selenoid"
    # default directory for browsers.json is /etc/selenoid/
    command: -listen :4444 -conf /etc/selenoid/browsers.json -video-output-dir /opt/selenoid/video/ -timeout 3m
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/etc/selenoid/ # assumed current dir contains browsers.json
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  selenoid-ui:
    container_name: selenoid-ui
    network_mode: bridge
    image: "aerokube/selenoid-ui"
    links:
      - selenoid
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    command: ["--selenoid-uri", "http://selenoid:4444"]

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: "nginx"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins/workspace/allure-report:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro,rslave
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: the easiest way to get access to the dynamic data is to use **volumes_from** in that container you want to look from.

When I configured my compose file like that I faced another issue - the 403 status has gone but the data was static. But that was my fault, I didn't use "cp -r  " command correctly so my data has been copied only once.